# Delay a click event until AJAX has completed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have written an AJAX script that saves form data and then displays a preview page of this data **all in one click event**. Here is the script:

```
$('#ajax-preview').click(function(e) {

    var formData =  $('#advertiser-edit-form').serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
       type: 'post' ,
       url: "ajax-preview.php",
       data: formData,
       success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
            previewURL = data;
            $('#ajax-preview').attr('href', previewURL);       
       }           
    });        
});
```

The problem is that sometimes the PHP script does not manage to complete its saving routine before a user is taken to the preview page. In such case, the user would see unupdated data when he's taken to the preview page. Then he would have to reload the page to see the changes.

How can I design the script so that a user is taken to the `previewURL` only after the AJAX updated the data?

Comment: What do you think this line `$('#ajax-preview').attr('href', previewURL);` does? Redirect to the `previewURL` page?

Comment: @hindmost: It's not immediately obvious, but he's updating the `href` on the link that was clicked, expecting the updated `href` to be used when the click's default action occurs.

Comment: @hindmost T.J. Crowder is correct. There is no redirection in the script itself. Only the link's URL is creted dynamically. The click event is supposed to the the user to this URL.

Comment: @luqo33 The problem is that AJAX request is **asynchronous**. So you cannot change link's URL **before** it applied on click event. If you want to forward user to other page after AJAX request is completed, you have to use `window.location` methods/properties such as `location.replace()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the code in your `click` handler only **starts** the ajax call, it doesn't wait for it to complete, and so the click's default behavior (following the link) occurs immediately, while the ajax call is still running. You can't make the click event wait unless you want to make the ajax call synchronous, which makes for a poor UX.

Instead, I suggest having a button the user presses to generate the preview, which makes the ajax call, and then have the ajax result reveal (unhide) a link the user can click to see the preview.

Rough example:

```js
$("#btn-create-preview").click(function() {
  var pending = $("#preview-pending"),
      msg = $("#preview-message"),
      btn = this;
  btn.disabled = true;
  msg.hide();
  pending.fadeIn("fast");
  // Simulate ajax via setTimeout
  setTimeout(function() {
    // This is the ajax completion function
    pending.hide();
    msg.find("a").attr(
      "href",
      "http://example.com?x=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)
    );
    msg.fadeIn("fast");
    btn.disabled = false;
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn-create-preview" value="Create Preview">
<em id="preview-pending" style="display: none">
  Building your preview...
</em>
<span id="preview-message" style="display: none">
  Your preview is ready;
  <a href="">click here</a>
  to view it.
</span>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer and a reasonable solution to the problem. I really appreciate your effort.